# Firebase Cloud Firestore doesn't show all entries in console

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple app, where I can submit an id (String), to firebase firestore and it saves an object with the id and current time.

While testing I noticed one thing: when I delete data from firestore straight through console, my application still thinks, that the data is in the database and when I add data through console, my application doesn't see it. It only works properly when data is added and deleted from my application. Why is that? Shouldn't application just see what's currently in the database without this weird behaviour?

How I am getting data from database while testing:

```
  static Future<void> printEntries() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await songList.snapshots().first;
    snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
      print('Element in database: ${element['id']}');
    });
    print('***************');
  }
```

This function is getting called when I click a button. Nothing fancy.

songList is a variable declared earlier like this:

```
  static final CollectionReference songList = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MyRoom');
```

I tried deleting whole collection, but somehow my application still gets the data that was saved previously even though, firestore console doesn't show it.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore caches data for you, if you want to get the updated data you need to listen to such event using,

```js
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
    });
```

Reference: [Listening to firestore collection changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)